# Wordpress: How to get the ID of each post on a archive page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-6

I've started working on a wordpress theme for Full-site-editing but now I need to get the ID of each post shown on the archive page.

My archive.html looks like this:

```
<!-- wp:template-part {"slug":"topbar","tagName":"topbar","className":"site-topbar"} /-->
<!-- wp:template-part {"slug":"header","tagName":"header","className":"site-header"} /-->
<!-- wp:group {"align":"full","className":"site-inner"} -->
<div class="wp-block-group alignfull site-inner">
    <!-- wp:group {"className":"content-sidebar-wrap"} -->
    <div class="wp-block-group content-sidebar-wrap">
        <!-- wp:group {"tagName":"main","align":"wide","className":"site-content"} -->
        <main class="wp-block-group alignwide site-content">
            <!-- wp:group {"align":"wide","layout":{"inherit":true}} -->
            <div class="wp-block-group alignwide">
                <!-- wp:group {"align":"wide"} -->
                <div class="wp-block-group alignwide">
                    <!-- wp:pattern {"slug":"theamy/archive-title"} /-->
                    <!-- wp:term-description /-->
                </div>
                <!-- /wp:group -->
            </div>
            <!-- /wp:group -->
            <!-- wp:pattern {"slug":"theamy/query-archive-grid"} /-->
        </main>
        <!-- /wp:group -->
    </div>
    <!-- /wp:group -->
</div>
<!-- /wp:group -->
<!-- wp:template-part {"slug":"footer","tagName":"footer","className":"site-footer"} /-->
```

and my archive query looks like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Title: Grid of posts in one column.
 * Slug: theamy/query-archive-grid
 * Categories: theamy-query
 */
?>

<!-- wp:group {"tagName":"section","align":"full","layout":{"inherit":true}} -->
<section class="is-layout-constrained wp-block-group alignfull theamy-query-archive-grid">
    <?php do_action('query-archive-grid-start'); ?>

    <!-- wp:query {"queryId":0,"query":{"perPage":12,"pages":0,"offset":0,"postType":"post","order":"desc","orderBy":"date","author":"","search":"","exclude":[],"sticky":"","inherit":true,"taxQuery":null},"displayLayout":{"type":"grid"},"align":"wide","layout":{"inherit":false},"lock":{"move":false,"remove":false}} -->
    <div class="wp-block-query alignwide">
        <!-- wp:post-template {"align":"wide"} -->
        <!-- wp:group {"tagName":"article","layout":{"inherit":false}} -->
        <article class="wp-block-group">
            <!-- wp:post-featured-image {"isLink":true} /-->

            <!-- wp:group {"tagName":"header","className":"entry-header","layout":{"inherit":false}} -->
            <header class="wp-block-group entry-header">
                <!-- wp:group {"className":"entry-meta","layout":{"type":"block"}} -->
                <div class="wp-block-group entry-meta">
                    <!-- wp:post-date {"format":"j F Y"} /-->
                </div>
                <!-- /wp:group -->

                <!-- wp:post-title {"isLink":true} /-->
            </header>
            <!-- /wp:group -->

            <!-- wp:group {"className":"entry-content","layout":{"inherit":false}} -->
            <div class="wp-block-group entry-content">
                <!-- wp:post-excerpt {"moreText":"Lees verder","showMoreOnNewLine":true} /-->
            </div>
            <!-- /wp:group -->

            <!-- wp:group {"tagName":"footer","className":"entry-footer","layout":{"inherit":false}} -->
            <footer class="wp-block-group entry-footer"></footer>
            <!-- /wp:group -->
        </article>
        <!-- /wp:group -->
        <!-- /wp:post-template -->

        <!-- wp:query-pagination {"align":"wide","layout":{"type":"flex","justifyContent":"center"}} -->

        <!-- wp:query-pagination-previous {"label":"<"} /-->

        <!-- wp:query-pagination-numbers /-->

        <!-- wp:query-pagination-next {"label":">"} /-->

        <!-- /wp:query-pagination -->
        <!-- wp:query-no-results -->
        <!-- wp:paragraph -->
        <p><?php echo __('Geen resultaten gevonden.', 'theamy') ?></p>
        <!-- /wp:paragraph -->
        <!-- /wp:query-no-results -->
    </div>
    <!-- /wp:query -->
</section>
<!-- /wp:group -->
```

I've tried to use get_the_ID() and get_queried_object_id(); but this did not seem to work.

I hope there's an easy fix for this but I could sadly not find it.

*Each post is put in a `<li>` with a class called "post-{id}", so I could use javascript to retrieve the post id but I'm not sure if that will do the trick for me and I rather not use javascript if it is not necessary.*

thank you in advance for the help.

Kind regards,
Janwillem